# Creating Lists from Multiple Jsons with Missing Keys

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create lists from json datas by pulling one by one and append them to the lists. However, some variables does not given in all json files. For example: for the json file below, data does not have `['statistics']['aerialLost']` , so it return Key Error. My Expected solution is when json file does not have key, append `'None'` value to the list and continue.

Code

```
s_aerialLost = []
s_aerialWon = []
s_duelLost = []
s_duelWon = []

players = ['Martin Linnes', 'Christian Luyindama', 'Marcão', 'Ömer Bayram', 'Oghenekaro Etebo', 'Muhammed Kerem Aktürkoğlu', 'Gedson Fernandes', 'Emre Kılınç', 'Ryan Babel', 'Mostafa Mohamed', 'Florent Hadergjonaj', 'Tomáš Břečka', 'Duško Tošić', 'Oussama Haddadi', 'Kristijan Bistrović', 'Aytaç Kara', 'Haris Hajradinović', 'Armin Hodžić', 'Gilbert Koomson', 'Isaac Kiese Thelin']
players_id = [109569, 867191, 840951, 68335, 839110, 903324, 862055, 202032, 1876, 873551, 354860, 152971, 14557, 867180, 796658, 128196, 254979, 138127, 341107, 178743]

for player, player_id in zip(players, players_id):
    
    url = base_url + str(player_id)
    data = requests.request("GET", url).json()

## just added 4 data for simplify
 
    accurateLongBalls = str(data['statistics']['accurateLongBalls'])
    aerialLost = str(data['statistics']['aerialLost'])
    aerialWon = str(data['statistics']['aerialWon'])
    duelLost = str(data['statistics']['duelLost'])
    s_aerialLost.append()
    s_aerialWon.append()
    s_duelLost.append()
    s_duelWon.append()
```

Json File

```
{
  "player": {
    "name": "Martin Linnes",
    "slug": "martin-linnes",
    "shortName": "M. Linnes",
    "position": "D",
    "userCount": 339,
    "id": 109569,
    "marketValueCurrency": "€",
    "dateOfBirthTimestamp": 685324800
  },
  "team": {
    "name": "Galatasaray",
    "slug": "galatasaray",
    "shortName": "Galatasaray",
    "gender": "M",
    "userCount": 100254,
    "nameCode": "GAL",
    "national": false,
    "type": 0,
    "id": 3061,
    "teamColors": {
      "primary": "#ff9900",
      "secondary": "#ff0000",
      "text": "#ff0000"
    }
  },
  "statistics": {
    "totalPass": 32,
    "accuratePass": 22,
    "totalLongBalls": 7,
    "accurateLongBalls": 3,
    "totalCross": 2,
    "aerialWon": 1,
    "duelLost": 2,
    "duelWon": 7,
    "totalContest": 3,
    "wonContest": 2,
    "totalClearance": 4,
    "totalTackle": 3,
    "wasFouled": 1,
    "fouls": 1,
    "minutesPlayed": 82,
    "touches": 63,
    "rating": 7.3,
    "possessionLostCtrl": 18,
    "keyPass": 1
  },
  "position": "D"
}
```

Error

```
KeyError: 'aerialLost'
```

Comment: Use `dictionary.get('key')` instead of `dictionary['key']`. It returns `None` by default instead of raising an error.

Comment: i changed variables like ```player_name = str(data['player']['name'])``` to ```player_name = str(data.get('player')('name')) ```. It gives ```TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable``` error.

Comment: `data.get('player', {}).get('name')`

Comment: You have to use `.get()` at each level of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get()`. You can specify a default value to return if the key is not found, and it defaults to `None`.

So you can use

```
aerialLost = str(data.get('statistics', {}).get('aerialLost'))
```

The first call defaults to an empty dictionary so that there's something to make the second `.get()` call on. The second call just returns the default `None`.